# Is there a device or executable on Windows that can provide cryptographically secure random bytes via CMD or Powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, cryptography

Essentially, I'm looking for the Windows equivalent of `/dev/urandom` on Linux.

I know I can use Windows CNG via the C++ APIs, but no idea if there's an available (portable) method to access random bytes on any modern Windows system via command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you can use through .NET (e.g. C#) you can also use through PowerShell, and this includes the [Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator) class. (In .NET Core 2.x, this class is implemented via CNG *BCryptGenRandom()* on Windows, OpenSSL *RAND_bytes()* on Linux, AppleCrypto *CCRandomGenerateBytes()* on macOS.)

```
$bytes = New-Object byte[](8)
$rng = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create()
$rng.GetBytes($bytes)
```

*(Code adapted from [CryptoGetRandom.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-version-of-Get-Random-d868af29) from Microsoft's "Script Center". The original script uses the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class, which is nearly the same thing but unavailable on ancient .NET 1.x runtime versions.)*

Comment: In PowerShell Core/PowerShell 6+, this can be shortened to one line: `[System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::GetBytes(8)`